# Заполнение ячеек таблицы из данных API по таймеру

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, таймер, таблицы

Пытаюсь осваивать Python с целью реализовать задуманное, но сейчас окончательно зашел в тупик. Вводные данные такие: есть программа, выводящая в графическом виде в окне таблицу. Есть запрос через api на получение значения, которое вписывается в соответствующую ячейку. Пока все работает. Но нужно сделать так, чтобы данные (получаемые через api) обновлялись по таймеру. В отрыве от таблицы я могу реализовать задумку через цикл while и time.sleep:

```
import requests
import json 
import time

while True:
    s=requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=BTC-TRX')
    data = s.json()
    k = data["result"][0]["Last"]
    btctrx = "%.8f" % k    
    time.sleep(60)
```

А вот как подобное реализовать в рамках программы, ума не приложу. Использование time.sleep останавливает выполнение программы и начинает бесконечный цикл (что, впрочем, ожидаемо). Подскажите, как можно по таймеру посылать запросы к api и результат вписывать в ячейки таблицы?

На данный момент мои потуги имеют вид:

```
import requests
import json 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt


class Sheet(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(600, 300))
        self.setWindowTitle("Table_title")
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)

        table = QTableWidget(self)
        table.setColumnCount(3)
        table.setRowCount(3)

        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["A", "B", "C"])
        table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(["1","TRX","3"])

        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

# API - start
        s=requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=BTC-TRX')
        data = s.json()
        k = data["result"][0]["Last"]
        btctrx = "%.8f" % k             
# API - end

        table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem())
        table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem())
        table.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem())
        table.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem(btctrx))

        table.resizeColumnsToContents()

        grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = Sheet()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Таблица со "статичным" значением:

[image: Примерный вид таблицы со статическим значением]

Comment: Ваш вопрос оформлен просто шикарно (без сарказма): описание понятное и с примером, код рабочий и полностью приложен, что позволит сразу его запустить и исправить :) Неудержался :)

Comment: Благодарю. Надеюсь кто-то сможет подсказать решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой и наглядный способ цикличного вызова кода и так чтобы не занимать основной поток это `QTimer`:

```
import requests

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QTimer


class Sheet(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(600, 300))
        self.setWindowTitle("Table_title")

        central_widget = QWidget()

        grid_layout = QGridLayout()

        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)

        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["A", "B", "C"])
        self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(["1", "TRX", "3"])

        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_table)
        self.timer.start(60 * 1000)

        self.update_table()

        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0)

        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def update_table(self):
        # Удаляем строки таблицы
        while self.table.rowCount():
            self.table.removeRow(0)

        self.table.setRowCount(3)

        # API - start
        rs = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=BTC-TRX')
        data = rs.json()
        print(data)
        k = data["result"][0]["Last"]
        btctrx = "%.8f" % k
        # API - end

        self.table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem())
        self.table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem())
        self.table.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem())
        self.table.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem(btctrx))

        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = Sheet()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

Если обновление данных происходит долго, тогда интерфейс будет подлагивать, в этом случае получение данных нужно вынести в отдельный поток и через сигналы-слоты обмениваться с ним данными:

```
import time

import requests

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal as Signal


class CheckNewData(QThread):
    about_new_data = Signal(dict)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # API - start
            rs = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=BTC-TRX')
            data = rs.json()
            print(data)
            # API - end

            self.about_new_data.emit(data)

            time.sleep(60)


class Sheet(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(600, 300))
        self.setWindowTitle("Table_title")

        central_widget = QWidget()

        grid_layout = QGridLayout()

        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)

        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["A", "B", "C"])
        self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(["1", "TRX", "3"])

        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.thread = CheckNewData()
        self.thread.about_new_data.connect(self.update_table)
        self.thread.start()

        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0)

        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def update_table(self, data):
        print('update_table:', data)

        k = data["result"][0]["Last"]
        btctrx = "%.8f" % k

        # Удаляем строки таблицы
        while self.table.rowCount():
            self.table.removeRow(0)

        self.table.setRowCount(3)

        self.table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem())
        self.table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem())
        self.table.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem())
        self.table.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem(btctrx))

        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = Sheet()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

**PS.** дополнительно:

- можно не очищать таблицу, а только обновлять данные в ячейках
- можно хранить предыдущие данные из сайта и при их изменении что-то делать, или больше -- менять только те ячейки, которые изменились
- можно вместо `QTableWidget` использовать `QTableView` + <сделать свою модель>, тогда достаточно будет менять только данные модели

Comment: Спасибо большое. Про "сигналы-слоты" и "QTableView модель" я, признаться, пока ничего не знаю - буду разбираться. Но код работает - это здорово!